# array_push not working in foreach loop

Tags: php, foreach, array-push

I have encountered a problem when trying to add values to an array through a foreach loop.
 Basically I have this form where there's a bunch of topics that the user can click 'like' or 'dislike' on with two radio-buttons per topic. I then want to collect the "likes" and the "dislikes" in two separate arrays, and insert them into a database, but something I don't do correct.
Here is a sample from the HTML code:

```
Action movies  Like<input type="radio" name="1" value="1" />  Dislike<input type="radio" id="2" name="1" value="2" />
```

And the PHP code:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $likes = array();
    $dislikes = array();

    foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {

        /* $key is the name of the object an user can click "like" or "dislike" on, $value   
        is either 'like', which is equal to '2' or 'dislike', equal to '1' */
        if ($value > 1) { array_push($likes, $key); } else { array_push($dislikes, $key); 
    }
} 
echo 'The object(s) the user likes: ' . $likes . ' , 
       and the object(s) the user dislikes: ' . $dislikes;
```

I however receive this:

**"The object(s) the user likes: Array , and the object(s) the user dislikes: Array"**

I'm sure it's just some stupid mistake I make here. I have googled this quite a lot but I have not been able to find any solution that helps me.

Comment: Id & name can't be only numbers (or starting with one)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An array when cast to a string will simply be output as the string `"Array"`. If you want to output *each element in the array*, loop through them or use something like `join`:

```
echo join(', ', $likes);
```

`array_push` is working just fine.

Comment: +1, But curious why you used the alias `join()` vs. `implode()` directly?

Comment: Cause it makes more sense to me and doesn't have any downsides.

Comment: join(', ', $likes); worked perfectly. Thanks for the quick answer.

Comment: @Danny BTW, `$likes[] = $key;` is the usual idiom instead of `array_push`.

Comment: @deceze, is there some reason for $likes[] = $key; being more usual than array_push?